# Script não continua e trava

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte código feito com `javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#loginForm").on("submit", function(a) {
      a.preventDefault(), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Autenticando...");

      var user = $("#username").val();
      var pass = $("#password").val();

      if (user == "") {
        $("#error").css("display", "block"), $('#error').html("<i class='fa fa-warning'></i> Insira seu usuário do Twitter"), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar");
      }

      else if (pass == "") {
        $("#error").css("display", "block"), $('#error').html("<i class='fa fa-warning'></i> Insira sua senha do Twitter"), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar");
      } else {
        $("#error").hide();
      }

      var b = $("#username").val();

      0 == /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$/.test(b) ? ($("#error").css("display", "block"), $("#error").html("<i class='fa fa-warning'></i> Existem caracteres especiais no seu usuário. Se estiver usando <strong>@</strong> remova-o!"), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar")) : $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/login.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
        success: function(a) {
          1 == a.redirect ? window.location = "index.php" : ($("#error").css("display", "block"), $("#error").html(a.message)), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar");
        }
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

Ta funcionando certinho, verificando campos vazios, se existe caracteres especais... Se preenchido corretamente fica **Autenticando...** e não continua meu script, repare que estou usando URL: `"api/login.php"` e `dataType: "JSON",`

Este é o arquivo em `api/login.php`:

```
<?php

require_once '../modules/autoload.php';

$ttrUsername = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username'));
$ttrPassword = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'));


$ch = curl_init();

$sTarget = "https://twitter.com";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ROOT . 'api' . SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . SEPARATOR . $ttrUsername . '.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, ROOT . 'api' . SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . SEPARATOR . $ttrUsername . '.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
}

preg_match('<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token">', $html, $match);

$authenticity_token = $match[1];

if ($authenticity_token == "") {       
  preg_match('<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token">', $html, $matchprima);   
  $authenticity_token = $matchprima[1];
}


$username = $ttrUsername;
$password = $ttrPassword;

$sPost = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

$sTarget = "https://twitter.com/sessions";  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

# display server response
$htmldos = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $htmldos, $matches);

$cookies = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

return json_decode($htmldos);
```

O que está errado neste código? Tanto o JavaScript quanto o PHP, eu estou retornando um `json` em `api/login.php`, mas não está funcionando.

Comment: Por quê você retorna `json_decode`? Não seria `json_encode`? E aparece algum erro no console? Já testou utilizar a *callback* de erro do AJAX no jQuery para saber se deu erro na requisição?

Comment: Não aparece nenhum erro no console, o pior que não sei utilizar *callback* do AJAX poderias me ajudar? PS: Troquei pra `json_encode` continua na mesma

Comment: Semelhante ao `success`: `error: function (error) { console.log(error); }`

Comment: Ok usei isto e no console mostra o seguite: http://prntscr.com/fq4msr/direct

Comment: Veja que a requisição possui status 200, então foi feita corretamente, mas você não está retornando um JSON válido, então o jQuery considera como erro.

Comment: Vixi, vc tem ideia de como retornar este código com json válido ?

Comment: Como perguntei no primeiro comentário: por quê está retornando `json_decode`?

Comment: Eu troquei para `json_encode` e continua só no **Autenticando...**

Comment: Qual o valor de `$htmldos`?

Comment: Isto http://prntscr.com/fq4r5q/direct

Comment: E qual é o JSON que deseja gerar?

Comment: Na verdade eu estou tentando ler o JSON mas eu ví aqui, não tem JSON nenhum no meu código PHP... você tem ideia de como fazer esta autenticação usando json? semelhante a este site: ve o código fonte dele: http://twitterlike.com.br/login.php

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61388/discussion-between-willbb-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, com ajuda [desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155192/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return) em inglês. Eu tive que fazer uma verificação antes para retornar o json, veja:

```
if (isset($cookies['auth_token'])) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=> "<div class='alert alert-success'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Autenticação bem sucedida, estamos te redirecionando</div>"));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message'=> "<div class='alert alert-danger'><i class='fa fa-warning'></i> Não foi possível autenticar com o Twitter.</div>"));
}
```

Acima está a verificação, abaixo o restante do código.

```
<?php

require_once '../modules/config.php';
require_once '../modules/class/Cookies.php';

$ttrUsername = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username'));
$ttrPassword = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'));


$ch = curl_init();

$sTarget = "https://twitter.com";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ROOT . 'api' . SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . SEPARATOR . $ttrUsername . '.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, ROOT . 'api' . SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . SEPARATOR . $ttrUsername . '.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token">', $html, $match);

$authenticity_token = $match[1];

if ($authenticity_token == "") {       
  preg_match('<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token">', $html, $matchprima);   
  $authenticity_token = $matchprima[1];
}


$username = $ttrUsername;
$password = $ttrPassword;

$sPost = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

$sTarget = "https://twitter.com/sessions";  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

# display server response
$htmldos = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $htmldos, $matches);

$cookies = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}

if (isset($cookies['auth_token'])) {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','message'=> "<div class='alert alert-success'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Autenticação bem sucedida, estamos te redirecionando</div>"));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error','message'=> "<div class='alert alert-danger'><i class='fa fa-warning'></i> Não foi possível autenticar com o Twitter.</div>"));
}
```